# DataSet.HasChanges not work for selected row (onClick MenuStrip)

Tags: c#, datagridview, dataset, menustrip

I have a datagridview binded with MyDataSet.

At form load, I fill the datagridview with this command:

```
MyTableAdapter.Fill(this.MyDataSet.ExtractData);
```

Now, I've added a MenuStrip and I want to get MyDataSet changes when I click on File/Save, but **if I change only one row and that row remains selected**, when I click File/Save no change is detected, and `MyDataSet.HasChanges()` always returns false.

`MyDataSet.HasChanges()` returns true only if I click on a button or another form object, not if I click on MenuStrip.

Why? There is a workaround? (I've tried to call EndEdit on the Dgv and to update the dataSet, but does not work...)

Comment: The only way I've found is to call `AnotherObject.Focus()` before checking `HasChanges`, and then re set the focus to the dgv... But it isn't marvelous...

Answer (score 0):

Use this before menu opens:

```
dataGridView.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
```

Comment: I've tried to put this line in the menu's onClick event, but still doesn't work...